# How to check the equal indexes of two different Arrays and put the correct value

Tags: java, android, arrays

Considering I have two arrays for example:

```
String [] countrys = {"USA", "AUSTRALIA"}; // indexes 0,1

String [] numberStates = {"50", "6"}; //indexes 0,1
```

I am a little amateur in this of the arrays and assign the correct value to equal indexes.

What I am looking for is to assign the correct value, for example, from the US country, assign 50 states and the next one is Austrlia to assign the 6 states.

I have searched for similar tutorials, but I still do not have a clear idea how to assign the correct indexes of 2 arrays.

```
 //complete code snippet

 Unit<Length> AddCorrectNumberStateToCountry = null;

 String queryCountry = “USA”

 String[] countrys = {"USA", "AUSTRALIA"};

 String[] numberStates = {"50", "6"};


 for(int t = 0; t < countrys.length; t++) {
 if (queryCountry.contains(countrys [t])) {

 AddCorrectNumberStateToCountry = STATES.plus(?????); 
 //here need know put exactly numberStates value by check index  STATES.plus(?)                 

 }
 }
```

Comment: You should look into making these hashmaps with <String,Integer>.

Comment: Jon Skeet calls this way of storing things [parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) and he explains why it's not good. You should declare your own class `Country` and keep a `Set<Country>`

Comment: Jon Skeet I just need to add according to
each corresponding index of each array, so that it takes the corresponding number

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to Elliott Frisch, he was right, my mistake was mine

For some mysterious reason, the value of states in number 1 threw me nuller point

```
double [] numberStates = {1 /* <---- nuller point 
i change to 0 and solve my problem */, 
50, 6};
```

Also change the array from int to double

---

The answer of Elliot Frisch

First, you should decide on appropriate types for the values. A number of states can be represented as an int (not clear why you would want a String or a Unit). The plural of "country" is "countries". And you can do something like,

```
String queryCountry = "USA";
String[] countries = { "USA", "AUSTRALIA" };
int[] numberStates = { 50, 6 };
int statesInCountry = -1;
for (int t = 0; t < countries.length; t++) {
if (countries[t].contains(queryCountry)) {
    statesInCountry = numberStates[t];
}
}
```

But a Map or a custom Java type would be better.

Many thanks to Elliot Frisch.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class like this:

```
public class CountryInfo {
private String name;
private int numberOfStates;

public CountryInfo(String name, int numberOfState)  {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfStates = numberOfStates;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumberOfStates() {
    return numberOfStates;
}
}
```

then

```
String [] countries = {"USA", "AUSTRALIA"}; // indexes 0,1
String [] numberStates = {"50", "6"}; //indexes 0,1
List<CountryInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberStates.length; i++) {
    list.add(new CountryInfo(countries[i]), numberStates[i]);
}
```

to access element, you can:

```
list.get(0).getName();
list.get(0).getNumberOfStates();
```